# Conversion from string type long error message box

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, messagebox

Rewriting an old program that was done in vba in vb. I have a for loop that checks to make sure a dropdown selection doesn't match other ddl selections. I am getting 'Conversion from String to type 'Long' is not valid' on the two MessageBox.Show lines, I have tried moving the And and & all around and still get the error. The commented out part is what I had in vba. How should the syntax be?

```
 Dim TCi(0 To 3) As String
        TCi(1) = "Air Temperature"
        TCi(2) = "Out Temperature(A)"
        TCi(3) = "Inlet"

        Dim TCj(0 To 3) As String
        TCj(1) = "Air Temperature"
        TCj(2) = "Out Temperature(A)"
        TCj(3) = "Inlet"

        SelectionFlagA = 0
        SelectionFlagB = 0
        TCSflag = 0
        For i = 1 To 3
            TCChannel = Me.Controls.Item("TCSDropDown" & i).Text
            If TCChannel = "Channel_Not_Available" Then
            ElseIf TCChannel = "Select Temp" Then
                TCSflag = TCSflag + 1
                'This code works
                MessageBox.Show("You selected the same temp for both" & TCi(i) & " and " & TCj(j), "Conflicting Temp Selection!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Exit For
            Else
                If InStr(1, TCChannel, "A") Then
                    SelectionFlagA = 1
                End If
                If InStr(1, TCChannel, "B") Then
                    SelectionFlagB = 1
                End If

                For j = 1 To 3

                    If TCi(i) <> TCj(j) Then
                        TCChannel1 = Me.Controls.Item("TCSDropDown" & j).Text
                        If TCChannel1 = "Channel_Not_Available" Then
                        Else
                            If TCChannel = TCChannel1 Then
                                'This code works
                                MessageBox.Show("You selected the same temp for both " & TCi(i) And "" & TCj(j), vbCritical, "Conflicting Temp Selection!")
                                'VBA Line: MsgBox "You selected the same temp for both " & TCi(i) & " and " & TCj(j), vbCritical, "Conflicting Temp Selection!"
                                TCSflag = TCSflag + 1
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
                If TCSflag >= 1 Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If


        Next
```

Comment: `And ""` probably should be `" and "`.  Be careful with typos, the editor tries to make sense of it and produce invalid code.  Also wrong at `And TCi(i)`

Comment: Or maybe  & "" And TCi(i)  should have been   & " " & TCi(i)

Comment: @HansPassant I tried that " And " TCi(i), and get a red underline and the error says "Comma, ')' or a valid expression continuation expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use exactly what the VBA code has

```
MessageBox.Show("Please select a temp for" & " " & TCi(i), "Error")
```

That said, there is no real point in concatenating a space after `... a temp for` like that. Just add it after the `for`  in the actual string.

```
MessageBox.Show("Please select a temp for " & TCi(i), "Error")
```

Comment: Hmm, when I try to use the exact VBA code, I get a red line under Show(). System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException. "No accessible 'Show' can be called without a narrowing conversion. Also, what do you mean by just add it after the  `for` . I understand about no need for space.

Comment: I added code for both suggestions. Look at the difference between the two code blocks. The second has a space after **for** before the closing quote

Comment: Gotcha, I tried that. I get syntax error under "Show". I tried adding a picture to my description but not showing? New to StackOverflow.

Comment: Remove the `vbCritical` or use the old style `MsgBox(...)`

Comment: Yup! I inserted the new code above, this works! Thank you for the help, had to update the arguments used.